# React problem hook useeffect return first element empty

Tags: reactjs

useEffect axios call returns an empty array followed by the expected result

```
const useGetProducts = (API) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await axios(API);
      setProducts(response.data)
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return products;
}
```

So when trying to use the result from the axios call, I get an undefined causing on an error.

```
<ProductItem product={product} />
```

[image]

Comment: how are you using your data inside `<ProductItem/>` component?

Comment: like this:  


function ProductItem({ product }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <img src={product.images[0]} alt={product.title} />
      </div>
    </div>    
  );
}

Comment: Your useGetProducts hook would work fine, if you only want to fetch the products once during initialization as mentioned by @Dorji Tshering. Regarding undefined, you can handle that by adding a check in ProductItem component. As follows: function ProductItem({ product }) {return product ? (<div> <div> <img src={product.images[0]} alt={product.title} /> </div> </div> ) : <p>Loading Product... </p>; };

Comment: Thanks, the code works, but i´m getting the same error on console. because of the empty array of results the api returns

Comment: So similar to what we did to ensure product is not undefined, we need to ensure images are present in your product. Transform your image code to : product?.images && product?.images?.length && <img src={product.images[0]} alt={product.title} />
This way you are writing safe code. You can use this approach for cases where you are not certain the property you are accessing actually exists.

Comment: If i comment the image code part, the app works well, I´m using the custom Hook with the useEffect on ProductsList page (with images working just fine) but with no reason the image does not show in Product Tiem page.

Comment: Also you can define the `fetchData()` function outside of **useEffect()** and keep the function call inside it for readability.

Answer (score 0):

When the dependency argument for `useEffect(callback, dependencies)` is an empty array, the callback(side-effect) runs only once after the initial rendering. So in your case, initially the value for your **products state** is an empty array as is set with **useState([])** hence, you get an empty array at the initial rendering. Only after which the callback function(side-effect) runs which updates the products after axios call and hence returns your actual products. More on that [here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useeffect-explanation/).

Comment: And how do I get actual products?  

try with useEffect(..., []), with no luck

Comment: Are you able to get the products anyway?

Comment: No, because the first empty result, the app breaks and throws an error.

Comment: Is this the kind of result you are getting? `[[], {product details of single product}]`

Comment: don´t know, 
  I´m getting this on console  {products: Array(0), error: '', loaded: false}
ProductItem.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: I am assuming, the console.logs are from two separate instance of re-rendering. Could you try what I suggested in my comment below your question?

Comment: It is expected that during the initial render, you will get **undefined** error since your products is an empty array. To stop that from happening, you can use an if statement in the `<ProductItem/>` component to check if the array is empty or not. If the array is empty, simply return a simple message inside **div** or **p** element, otherwise return what you plan to return.